# form_for for ordinary object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I use form_for orbinary object?

Controller:

```
class AgendaState
    attr_accessor :base_date

    def initialize(date)
        @base_date = date
    end
end

class TodayController < ApplicationController
    def agenda(base_date = Date.today)
        @agenda = AgendaState.new(base_date)
```

View:

```
<%= form_for(@agenda) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :base_date %>
<% end %>
```

Error message:

```
undefined method `model_name' for AgendaState:Class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be extend your class with ActiveModel

```
class AgendaState
 extend ActiveModel::Naming
 include ActiveModel::Conversion
 ...
end
```

Updated due to discussion in comments.

Comment: I get error "undefined method `to_key' for #<AgendaState:0x488a108 @base_date=Mon, 26 Mar 2012>" in this case

Comment: also add include ActiveModel::Conversion to your class.

Comment: I have found http://mrjaba.posterous.com/rails-3-active-model-undefined-method-tokey-f, but stops on undefined method `agenda_states_path' for #<#<Class:0x3fcfb70>:0x3cf4e00>

Comment: well go to http://railscasts.com/episodes/219 to see the description and here https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-219/messenger for example